# EF Core composite class into same table

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

I've been searching everywhere and reading the documentation, but I can't seem to find a similar scenario as mine.

The situation is the following.
In C# I have 3 classes:

```
[Table("my_baseline_table")]
class Baseline
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public ClassA ClassA { get; set; }
   public ClassB ClassB { get; set; }
}

class ClassA
{
   public string Property1 { get; set; }
   public string Property2 { get; set; }
   public string Property3 { get; set; }
}

class ClassB
{
   public string Property4 { get; set; }
   public string Property5 { get; set; }
   public string Property6 { get; set; }
}
```

My classes "ClassA" and "ClassB" have a higher number of properties in reality, around 12 each, just trying to keep it simple.

Then on SQL I have a single table with all the columns:

```
dbo.my_baseline_table
   id
   property1
   property2
   property3
   property4
   property5
   property6
```

Right now I don't know how to tell EF this relationship.
As such, it starts complaining that "Class A" needs to have an id and so on.

The reason I have these properties separated in 2 classes, is because it will make it a lot easier for me to create some JSON files based on it, without having to pick each property individually.

Anyone know how this can be achieve or other suggestions to have this work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is called an "[Owned Entity Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities)".  EG this

```
[Table("my_baseline_table")]
class Baseline
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ClassA ClassA { get; set; }
    public ClassB ClassB { get; set; }
}

[Owned]
class ClassA
{
    [Column(nameof(ClassA.Property1))]
    public string Property1 { get; set; }

    [Column(nameof(ClassA.Property2))]
    public string Property2 { get; set; }

    [Column(nameof(ClassA.Property3))]
    public string Property3 { get; set; }
}

[Owned]
class ClassB
{
    [Column(nameof(ClassB.Property4))]
    public string Property4 { get; set; }

    [Column(nameof(ClassB.Property5))]
    public string Property5 { get; set; }

    [Column(nameof(ClassB.Property6))]
    public string Property6 { get; set; }
}
```

maps to

```
  CREATE TABLE [my_baseline_table] (
      [Id] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
      [Property1] nvarchar(max) NULL,
      [Property2] nvarchar(max) NULL,
      [Property3] nvarchar(max) NULL,
      [Property4] nvarchar(max) NULL,
      [Property5] nvarchar(max) NULL,
      [Property6] nvarchar(max) NULL,
      CONSTRAINT [PK_my_baseline_table] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
  );
```

Comment: So simple! :D Thank you.
Marked this as an answer as it directly answer the question and it worked.
However after thinking it further, I've decided to go with Steve Py suggestion of using multiple DTOs, as will give me more flexibility in the long term for my use case.

Answer (score 2):

Entities should reflect the table structure. Producing Json is a separate concern which I would recommend declaring a DTO structure suitable for that purpose and projecting your entities into the DTO structure which can be serialized to JSON. Automapper is perfectly suited for operations like this and offers a `ProjectTo` method that integrates into EF's Linq implementation to generate queries.

```
// Entity
public class Baseline
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string Property1 { get; set; }
   // et. al.
}

// DTOs
[Serializable]
public class BaselineDTO
{ 
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ClassADTO ClassA { get; set; }
    public ClassBDTO ClassB { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
class ClassADTO
{
   public string Property1 { get; set; }
   public string Property2 { get; set; }
   public string Property3 { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
class ClassBDTO
{
   public string Property4 { get; set; }
   public string Property5 { get; set; }
   public string Property6 { get; set; }
}
```

Then when you go to read your data to serialize to JSON:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => 
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Baseline, BaselineDTO>()
       .ForMember(dest => dest.ClassA, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src))
       .ForMember(dest => dest.ClassB, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));
    cfg.CreateMap<BaseLine, ClassADTO>();
    cfg.CreateMap<BaseLine, ClassBDTO>();
});

var baselines = context.Baselines
    .Where(/* conditions */)
    .ProjectTo<BaselineDTO>(config)
    .ToList();
```

This will give you the desired structure to serialize to JSON. It looks a bit odd with mappings for the same source (entity) to three DTOs but provided the property names are consistent between the entity and DTOs Automapper will work out the values to copy across.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. 
I have to agree with your suggestion and I've decided to change my implementation to match your suggestion. 
This way will simpler for the DB mapping and will allow me to have DTOs for the different use cases of my API.
Unfortunately, I'm only to pick an answer in StackOverflow, as such I had to pick David Browne as it directly answers my query :(